# Histogram from Pandas data and specify groupby time

Tags: python, pandas

How do I make a histogram and find 90% and 95% values from the following output of bars:

```
bars = ticks.Volume.resample('1s', how=sum)
bars = bars.dropna()
bars

    Timestamp
2015-12-27 23:00:25     1.0
2015-12-27 23:01:11    10.0
2015-12-27 23:02:03     1.0
2015-12-27 23:02:14     2.0
2015-12-27 23:07:27     1.0
2015-12-27 23:14:58     2.0
2015-12-27 23:17:45     1.0
2015-12-27 23:21:38     1.0
2015-12-27 23:37:29     2.0
2015-12-27 23:37:32     1.0
2015-12-27 23:47:35     2.0
2015-12-27 23:47:38    12.0
2015-12-28 00:18:48     1.0
2015-12-28 00:26:19     1.0
2015-12-28 00:42:52     4.0
2015-12-28 01:25:52     1.0
2015-12-28 01:38:52     4.0
2015-12-28 02:03:47     4.0
2015-12-28 02:04:25     4.0
2015-12-28 02:39:15     3.0
2015-12-28 02:54:11     5.0
2015-12-28 03:07:43     1.0
2015-12-28 03:20:04     1.0
2015-12-28 03:30:00     6.0
2015-12-28 03:42:16     1.0
2015-12-28 04:11:03     6.0
2015-12-28 05:13:37     1.0
2015-12-28 05:15:20     1.0
2015-12-28 05:45:51     2.0
2015-12-28 05:48:14    29.0
```

Also how do I restrict this to only 09:30 - 16:15?  Should I use groupby?  If yes, can you please show how to do this?

thanks

Comment: is `Timestamp` an index or a column?

Comment: what do you mean saying `find 90% and 95% values`?

Comment: 95% (2 std deviations) and 90% of the distribution I believe is what is required.  Thanks

Comment: Help me understand what your bin sizes should be. Do you just want to let the histogram function pick the optimal bins? And I think you want the 95% confidence intervals, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi Kartik,  the percentages I listed were given to me by a friend and he is not available to discuss right now.  You are probably right so please go ahead on that basis if you can.  The optimal bins option is a great starting point and I look forward to seeing your code and learning from it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These tasks can easily be done using Numpy's `histogram` and `percentile` methods.

But first we filter by time of day by first converting the index to datetime objects. In the following example I have changed the target times to include observations in your example dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#EDIT: added code to rename a column
##
# Rename column
##
bars.columns  # check the original column names
>>>Index([u'Unnamed: 1'], dtype='object')

# rename the 'Unnamed: 1' column
bars.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1': 'Value'}, inplace=True)

bars.columns
>>>Index([u'Value'], dtype='object')

##
# Filter by time of day
##

# Convert to a datetime. 
# WARNING this is operation is very expensive. For very large dataframes, it is much faster
# to use keep the indices as text and use a different filtering function.
bars.index = bars.index.to_datetime()

# Changed the target times to include values in the sample df
start = (2, 30)
end = (5, 15)

# Filter to only keeps times of day that fall within the desired times
idx = pd.Series(bars.index).apply(lambda x: x.replace(hour=start[0], minute=start[1]) < x < x.replace(hour=end[0], minute=end[1])).values

bars_filtered = bars[idx]

bars_filtered 
                     Value
2015-12-28 02:03:47    4.0
2015-12-28 02:04:25    4.0
2015-12-28 02:39:15    3.0
2015-12-28 02:54:11    5.0
2015-12-28 03:07:43    1.0
2015-12-28 03:20:04    1.0
2015-12-28 03:30:00    6.0
2015-12-28 03:42:16    1.0
2015-12-28 04:11:03    6.0
```

Calculating the histograms and percentiles is very easy.

```
##
# Histograms and Percentiles
##

# Get the histograms
num_bins = 10
hist, edges = np.histogram(bars.Value, bins=num_bins)

hist
array([20,  7,  0,  2,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1])

# Edges defining the histogram bins
edges
array([  1. ,   3.8,   6.6,   9.4,  12.2,  15. ,  17.8,  20.6,  23.4,
    26.2,  29. ])

# Calculate the percentiles
p_90 = np.percentile(bars_filtered.Value, q=90)
p_95 = np.percentile(bars_filtered.Value, q=95)

p_90
6.0

p_95
6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this Andrew. My bars_filtered does not have a column name of 'Value' like yours.  How do I add this please.  Sorry for the basic question.                                                               'bars_filtered
​
Out[21]:
Timestamp
2015-12-28 02:03:47     4.0
2015-12-28 02:04:25     4.0
2015-12-28 02:39:15     3.0
2015-12-28 02:54:11     5.0
2015-12-28 03:07:43     1.0
2015-12-28 03:20:04     1.0'

Comment: I'm using python 3.5.1 and Pandas 0.18.0.  Is the code above still valid?  thanks

Comment: I added some code to rename the column. Since you are brand new to Pandas, I highly suggest you read through some of the tutorials. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/tutorials.html

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-8be604070a7a> in <module>()
      5 bars.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1': 'Value'}, inplace=True)
----> 7 bars.columns
generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2663         if (name in self._internal_names_set or name in self._metadata or
   2664                 name in self._accessors):
-> 2665             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2666         else:
   2667             if name in self._info_axis:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`

Comment: Thanks Andrew but I get the error. `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`

Comment: `bars
​
/Users/n/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:1: 
Out[10]:
Timestamp
2015-12-27 23:00:25     1.0
2015-12-27 23:01:11    10.0

(cut as too many characters)
2016-01-13 03:33:31     1.0
Name: Volume, dtype: float64`

Comment: I am using a Pandas DataFrame in my example. Apparently you are using a Series. Unfortunately the example you gave us lacks sufficient detail for me to know which data structure you were using. You will that on Stack Overflow you will get much better, and quicker answers if you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: But to help with your `AttributeError` you could use a `Series.rename`  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rename.html

Comment: Or you could convert your series to a DataFrame and then use my example.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html

Comment: Thanks for your patience Andrew.  I will work through your code and also try to provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example going forward.

Comment: One last question please Andrew.  Your code says "WARNING this is operation is very expensive. For very large dataframes, it is much faster
to use keep the indices as text and use a different filtering function."  What is the other approach you mention?

Comment: Also, I've never used the Lambda function so may have misunderstood but should `minute=start[0])` be `minute=start[1])` in order to utilise the minute element correctly?